getting pressure sensor(flutter)
void initState() {
super.initState();
barometer = Barometer(inMillis: 1000);
barometer.getRaw().listen((element) {
  setState(() {
    pressureValue = element.hectpascal;
    print(pressureValue);
  });
});

}
In this code, 'MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method listen on channel pressureStream)' error is occured.
I used 'sensor_library' plugin ver 0.1.0
(https://pub.dev/packages/sensor_library)
I tried to refer this code which official doc provided.
https://github.com/hraschan/flutter_sensor_library_app/blob/master/lib/routes/barometer_route.dart
And I tried to use code which official doc gave as an example, but same error existed.
